# How to access subObject properties values in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, subobject

I am trying to loop over an object properties and values and build a string with them.
The problem is i cant seem to access the values of the properties which are not string...

Here is what i have so far:

```
    private string ObjectToStringArray(CustomType initParameters)
    {
        var stringArray = "";

        foreach (var parameter in initParameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (parameter.PropertyType.Name == "String")
                stringArray += "\"" + parameter.Name + "\" => \"" + parameter.GetValue(initParameters) + "\",\r\n";
            else
            {
                stringArray += "array(\r\n";
                foreach (var subParameter in parameter.PropertyType.GetProperties())
                {
                    stringArray += "\"" + subParameter.Name + "\" => \"" + subParameter.GetValue(parameter) + "\",\r\n";
                }
                stringArray += "),";
            }
        }

        return stringArray;
    }
```

i can get to the values of all the string properties but one level down i just cant extract the property object itself.

My exception is: **System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.**

Comment: What is the output/exception, what did you expect to happen? (you can update your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `subParameter.GetValue(parameter)`, you are passing a [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), whereas you seemingly want to pass the value of that property for `initParameters` instead.

You should thus pass `parameter.GetValue(initParameters)` to `subParameter.GetValue()` instead.

Comment: This is the problem, how do i access that value?
Using `initParameters` returns the same excpetion.

Comment: @RealGigex Just like you output the value of the string by calling `parameter.GetValue(initParameters)`, so should you get the actual value of the property, rather than its `PropertyInfo` by calling `parameter.GetValue(initParameters)`. That call means, _"for this type of property, get the value for the specified instance that contains that property"_. In other words, `subParameter.GetValue(parameter.GetValue(initParameters))`, not just `subParameter.GetValue(initParameters)`. Just trying to make you understand what is going on. ;p P.s. you could probably use recursion to implement this.

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick!
I was also missing some null validations on the sub objects.